# Getting wrong output when using IN keyword db2

Tags: db2, dashdb

so this is my query :

```
select count(a.rs1) as partsProduced, a.DEVICEID ,a.DATA_MAINPROGRAMNO from (
    SELECT currow, rs1, rs2,DEVICEID,DATA_MAINPROGRAMNO
    FROM (
    SELECT current_row.row1  currow,
     current_row.DATA_RUNSTATUS rs1, 
     current_row.DEVICEID DEVICEID,
      current_row.DATA_MAINPROGRAMNO DATA_MAINPROGRAMNO,
     next_row.row1 nextrow,
     next_row.DATA_RUNSTATUS rs2
    FROM (SELECT rownumber() over(order by  DATA_TIMEINMILLISECS) as row1, m.* FROM "IOTP_SL2IID_GOVHISTORICALDB_2017-03-20"
    m where DEVICEID ='deviceName' ) AS current_row
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT rownumber() over(order by DATA_TIMEINMILLISECS) as row1, m.* FROM "IOTP_SL2IID_GOVHISTORICALDB_2017-03-20" m 
    where DEVICEID ='deviceName' ) AS next_row 
    ON (current_row.row1 = next_row.row1 - 1)
    where (TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(current_row.DATA_TIMESTAMP,'YYYY.MM.DD.HH24.MI.SS') 
    BETWEEN '2017-03-20 14:00:00' AND '2017-03-20 15:00:00')) AS a WHERE a.rs1 = 3 AND a.rs2 = 0) as a group by a.DEVICEID ,a.DATA_MAINPROGRAMNO;
```

I'm getting correct output in this where parts produced is 17 for that given hour, but whenever I replace `DEVICEID= 'deviceName'` to

```
DEVICEID IN ( select d.DEVICE_ID  from device d  left join line l  on ( l.id=d.LINE_ID ) where l.id=1
```

as I need multiple deviceNames and fire a query with that, now I'm getting 300 something for the same device which I ran earlier with single device, so am I using the IN keyword correct?? or is there any editing to do?

Comment: How many DEVICE_ID are returned from your subquery...?

Comment: @data_henrik 20, and btw they're names i.e., string

Answer (score 0):

Rahul,

Make sure DEVICE_ID values in table device are not null.If it values are not null then you can go ahead with ur existing query:

**DEVICEID IN ( select d.DEVICE_ID  from device d  left join line l  on ( l.id=d.LINE_ID ) where l.id=1**

If DEVICE_ID has null values  then use below query

**DEVICEID IN ( select distinct nvl(d.DEVICE_ID,0)  from device d  left join line l  on ( l.id=d.LINE_ID ) where l.id=1**

---